# Tiktok Query User Info API display internal_error

Tags: tiktok-api

Currently i'm trying to learning tiktok API from this doc [Research API](https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/research-api-get-started/). I'm testing it on my postman. my tiktok apps status still staging. I able to get the access token but for "[query videos](https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/research-api-specs-query-videos/)" and "[Query user info](https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/research-api-specs-query-user-info/)" endpoint i got this response :

```
{
    "data": {},
    "error": {
        "code": "internal_error",
        "message": "Something went wrong. Please try again later.",
        "log_id": "202303211519179C7650D3E1B2C10DAA52"
    }
}
```

i do message to tiktok support but i haven't get any reply from them these few days. Is anyone know about this? please help